# access node field variables in theming view-field

Tags: theming

How can I access a filed value of the node that I don't want to display in the view, is there any way to pass the field variable in $fields using view but not include it in display, I'm just want to use this field for checking a condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check "exclude from display" for this field.

Comment: Hi soju, if I do this I don't have the value of that field in templates file, for example I override views-view-field.tpl.php and $fields only contains fields that don not excluded from display. you can try it.

Comment: Then don't check exclude and override views-view-fields.tpl.php instead of views-view-field.tpl.php